# Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException when use content resolver in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am reading android messages, calendars data etc. using content resolver. i added permission into manifest file. and also implemented runtime permission for reading/writing SMS & calendar. still i am getting below issue on some devices which are running in android 7.0 or higher.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1693)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1646)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider (ActivityManagerNative.java:4912)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider (ActivityThread.java:6043)
  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContextImpl.java:2474)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContentResolver.java:1521)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:520)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:478)
  at com.allbackup.ui.activity.MsgsActivity.c (MsgsActivity.java:301)
  at com.allbackup.ui.activity.MsgsActivity$c.a (MsgsActivity.java:201)
  at com.allbackup.ui.activity.MsgsActivity$c.doInBackground (MsgsActivity.java:186)
```

above is the stacktrace of error while reading SMS. and below is the code for that:

```
Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
            //startManagingCursor(c);
            int totalSMS = c.getCount();

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")) != null){
                        add = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", "");
                        map.put("address", c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", ""));
                    }else{

                        map.put("address", "");
                    }
if(!add.isEmpty()){
                        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(add));
                        Cursor cno = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI},null,null,null);
                        if(cno.getCount()>0){
                            try {
                                cno.moveToFirst();
                                map.put("name", cno.getString(0));
                                map.put("photo", cno.getString(1));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }finally{
//                              cno.close();
                            }
                        }else{
                            map.put("name", "");
                            map.put("photo", "");

                        }
                        if(cno!=null)
                            cno.close();
                    }
}
```

I am getting error on below line:

```
Cursor cno = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI},null,null,null);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.allbackup">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you explicitly requesting all the permissions? In OS prior to Android O, requesting either of Read/Write permission used to grant all the permissions in that group. But Starting from Android O, you need to explicitly request for Read & Write permissions in order to get both the permissions

Comment: @Sagar i am not getting your point.

Comment: What I mean is: if you request permission `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR, requestCode);` then system used to grant Read&write calendar permission. But with new version you need to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, requestCode);`

Comment: @Sagar but i am also getting this error on android 7.0 and 7.1.

Comment: Do you check if the app has permission each time you access the provider, or just when the app starts? Just in case the user revokes the permission after the app has launched. You mention SMS and calendar, but do you have the android.permission.READ_CONTACTS permission?

Comment: @fejd yeah, i checked that. its fine..there is no issue regarding permission.

Comment: Please share your manifest permissions

Comment: @SamyB check now..

Answer (score 0):

For all the dangerous permissions you need to request permission at runtime. Please refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous-permission-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the content using content provider you have to check the permission all the time. if not granted , then you have to request the permission on run-time and then try to fetch message.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

read your contacts here

}
```

For more information please refer to this site : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en